Markdown Editor Styling Overwritten by @shadcn/ui Typography in React App
I’m working on a React application that uses @shadcn/ui for the UI framework and react-markdown for rendering Markdown content. My problem is that the Markdown content is not displaying correctly because the typography styles from @shadcn/ui are overriding the Markdown styles. Specifically, the Markdown headers and other text elements are not showing the expected formatting.
Here is the relevant part of my React component:
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { MarkdownFile, isHTTPValidationError } from "@/types"
import { useParams, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom"
import { fetchMarkdown, updateMarkdown } from "@/endpoint"
import { Button } from "./ui/button"
import Markdown from "react-markdown"
import rehypeHighlight from "rehype-highlight"
import remarkGfm from "remark-gfm"
import "./styles.css"

const MarkdownEdit: React.FC = () => {
  const [markdown, setMarkdown] = useState<MarkdownFile | null>(null)
  const { id } = useParams<{ id: string }>()
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  const [error, setError] = useState<string>("")

  useEffect(() => {
    if (id) {
      fetchMarkdown(id, setMarkdown)
    }
  }, [id])

  const handleSave = async (e: React.FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setError("")
    if (!markdown) return
    try {
      await updateMarkdown(markdown.id, markdown, setMarkdown)
      navigate("/")
    } catch (err: unknown) {
      if (isHTTPValidationError(err)) {
        setError((err as Error & { detail: string }).detail)
      } else {
        setError("An unknown error occurred.")
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        minHeight: "100vh",
        backgroundColor: "#F9FAFB",
      }}
    >
      {markdown && (
        <div
          style={{
            display: "flex",
            flexDirection: "column",
            height: "calc(100vh - 100px)", // Adjust this value as needed
            overflow: "hidden", // Prevents the page from scrolling
          }}
        >
          <h2
            style={{
              marginBottom: "0.5rem",
              fontSize: "1.875rem",
              fontWeight: "600",
            }}
          >
            Company: {markdown.company_name}
          </h2>
          <h4 style={{ fontSize: "1.25rem", fontWeight: "600" }}>
            Business: {markdown.business_type}
          </h4>
          {error && <div className="text-red-500 mb-4">{error}</div>}
          <div
            style={{
              display: "flex",
              flexDirection: "row",
              height: "100%", // Take up remaining space
              overflow: "hidden", // Prevents this div from scrolling
            }}
          >
            <textarea
              style={{
                flex: 1,
                width: "50%",
                overflowY: "auto",
                resize: "none",
              }}
              placeholder="Type your message here."
              value={markdown.products}
              onChange={(e) =>
                setMarkdown({ ...markdown, products: e.target.value })
              }
            />
            <div
              className="markdown-content"
              style={{
                flex: 1,
                width: "50%",
                overflowY: "auto",
                padding: "0.5rem",
              }}
            >
              <Markdown rehypePlugins={[rehypeHighlight, remarkGfm]}>
                {markdown.products}
              </Markdown>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
      <Button style={{ margin: "1rem" }} onClick={handleSave}>
        Save
      </Button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default MarkdownEdit

To solve this issue, I created a custom CSS class to override the global typography styles from @shadcn/ui. Here is the CSS:
/* styles.css */
.markdown-content h1,
.markdown-content h2,
.markdown-content h3,
.markdown-content h4,
.markdown-content h5,
.markdown-content h6 {
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
}

.markdown-content p {
  margin-top: inherit;
  margin-bottom: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
}

.markdown-content blockquote {
  font-size: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
  margin: inherit;
  padding: inherit;
  border-left: inherit;
  color: inherit;
}

.markdown-content ul,
.markdown-content ol {
  list-style: inherit;
  margin: inherit;
  padding: inherit;
}

.markdown-content table {
  width: inherit;
  border-collapse: inherit;
  margin: inherit;
}

By wrapping the Markdown component in a div with the markdown-content class, I ensured the Markdown styles were correctly applied:
<div className="markdown-content">
  <Markdown rehypePlugins={[rehypeHighlight, remarkGfm]}>
    {markdown.products}
  </Markdown>
</div>

Unfortunately, the header still doesn't show the correct format in the Markdown component.

